# How to set `rel="shortcut icon"` on image page?

Tags: html, icons, favicon

How to set `rel="shortcut icon"` on image page ?

When i access `EG: example.com/food.png`

I want to display rel="shortcut icon" on image page, how can i do that ?

In other php page i write `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="food.png">` in `<head>` tag

But in image page `EG: example.com/food.png` how to add rel="shortcut icon" ?

you can test on this link http://ir.ebaystatic.com/pictures/aw/homepage/eBayTodayCoverPhotos/UK/Sale_27062014_2.jpg you will see favicon of ebay , how can i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

All that you need to do is place image file favicon.ico in your main site directory eg public_html/favicon.ico place that way file with name and extension favicon.ico size 16x16 it will be shown in every pages of your site including in image preview also Here is example http://srpskalegija.bplaced.net/forumhtml/images/logo.gif

Comment: you can test on this link http://ir.ebaystatic.com/pictures/aw/homepage/eBayTodayCoverPhotos/UK/Sale_27062014_2.jpg


you will see favicon of ebay , how can i do that ?

Comment: In my site works also i didn't use any  code and it's showing favicon all i did is placed file favicon.ico in my main site directory eg public_html/favicon.ico place that way and try file name and extension favicon.ico size 16x16 Here is it http://srpskalegija.bplaced.net/forumhtml/images/logo.gif

Comment: @Ненад Your answer is right. When accessing http://example.com/path/to/pic.png, Chrome also tries to load http://example.com/favicon.ico as a side effect. I suggest you to rephrase your answer to make it more affirmative, rather than the "This might work" tone you used. Be proud of your suggestion! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="http://example.com/favicon.png">
```

This is achievable, just insert put the PNG image in your root directory the, linking absolutely will help. Put the above link tag in your head.

I guess the PNG image would work fine, but if it doesn't just convert your image to ico format and replace the type with ico. I suggest just converting it in .ico format as it has more support.Check this wiki link [Favicon Browser Implementation and Support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#Browser_implementation)

I've seen that some browsers do take time to display the favicon if you've changed it or added a new one, anyways it'll work fine. After you've done that, when you open any image suppose at this URL
example.com/img/one.png it'll show the favicon on the tab, that's what you want right? :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution.

```
    <link rel="icon" href="address" sizes="32x32">
  <link rel="icon" href="address" sizes="192x192">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="address">
  <meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="address">
```